# laravel array inside query results

Tags: php, laravel

I have query of data which some of it's data needs to be array but not sure how to get those arrays inside my query.

## Screenshot

[image: one]

I have `2 students` in `2 semester` and `4 different classes` what I try to achieve is to get each student `semester and classes` in array.

So I would have results such as this:

[image: two]

## code

```
$students = DB::table('schools')
            ->where('schools.id', $id)
            ->join('school_semesters', 'school_semesters.school_id', '=', 'schools.id')
            ->join('semester_classes', 'semester_classes.semester_id', '=', 'school_semesters.id')
            ->join('class_students', 'class_students.class_id', '=', 'semester_classes.id')
            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'class_students.user_id')
            ->select(
                'school_semesters.name as semester',
                'semester_classes.name as class',
                'users.name as students',
                'users.id as id'
            )
            ->groupBy('users.id') // return results as screenshot #2
            ->get();
```

**Any idea?**

## Update

expected result would be something like this:

```
semester: ["Winter semester", "Our Spring semester"]
class: ["A1", "B1"]
students: "Student Two"
id: 5
DT_RowId: 5
```

so `semester` and `class` will be array.

Comment: so your question is how to convert your query result into an array?

Comment: @Gamopo only semester and classes otherwise it is array already, (each user will have 2 arrays inside it's data)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your question is, can you add (in code style) what output you expect from the `DB` query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing a group by user.id. by using Group concat you'll get the expected result.

```
->select(
    \DB::raw('group_concat(DISTINCT school_semesters.name) as semester'),        
    \DB::raw('group_concat(DISTINCT semester_classes.name) as class'),
    'users.name as students',
    'users.id as id'
)
```

Comment: `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'GROUP_CONCAT(school_semesters.name)' in 'field list' `

Comment: Check I've updated with DB::raw query. check last updated query.